# Stepwise user count calculation on time variable

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using redshift SQL to solve this, I have a dataset which contains user level information on watch lengths of various videos. I want to find how many users watched 1sec, 2 sec, 3 sec and so on.

Table looks like this.

User ID.   Duration (in sec)
1 ----------            1
2 ---------            20 
3 ---------            4 
4  ---------           6

I want the output to be something like 
Time.     Number of users
1  --------         4
2  --------         3
3  --------         3
4  --------         3
5  --------         2
6  --------         2
7  --------         1

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query:

```
select Duration, count(*)
from Table
group by  Duration
order by ASC;
```

Comment: Durations are not integer, plus not necessarily every duration will exist in the data.

Comment: can you put example of durations ?